# svg line marker truncated when mask is used

Tags: html, svg, line, mask

I'm using a mask on a line to make a portion of it disappear.
This line has a marker on it.
When the line is getting vertical, some part of the marker is missing.
The same occurs when line is getting horizontal too.

I checked the mask dimension with chrome dev tools, it seems to be correct:
[image]

The issue has been identified in chrome and firefox.

Here is the code that reproduce the issue:

```html
<html>
<style>
    .link {
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<body>
<div id="svg-body">
    <svg viewBox="0,0,600,400">
        <defs>
            <marker id="end" viewBox="0 -5 10 10" refX="10" refY="0" markerWidth="6" markerHeight="6" orient="auto">
                <polyline points="0,-5 10,0 0,5"></polyline>
            </marker>
        </defs>
        <g class="link">
            <mask id="CP_0">
                <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
                <rect class="link-text-bg"
                      fill="black"
                      width="100"
                      height="20"
                      x="90"
                      y="250"
                ></rect>
            </mask>
            <line class="link-line" mask="url(#CP_0)" marker-end="url(#end)"
                  x1="100"
                  y1="200"
                  x2="140"
                  y2="300"></line>

        </g>

        <g class="link">
            <mask id="CP_1">
                <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
                <rect class="link-text-bg"
                      fill="black"
                      width="100"
                      height="20"
                      x="190"
                      y="250"
                ></rect>
            </mask>
            <line class="link-line" mask="url(#CP_1)" marker-end="url(#end)"
                  x1="200"
                  y1="200"
                  x2="210"
                  y2="300"></line>

        </g>

        <g class="link">
            <mask id="CP_2">
                <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
                <rect class="link-text-bg"
                      fill="black"
                      width="100"
                      height="20"
                      x="290"
                      y="250"
                ></rect>
            </mask>
            <line class="link-line" mask="url(#CP_2)" marker-end="url(#end)"
                  x1="300"
                  y1="200"
                  x2="302"
                  y2="300"></line>

        </g>


    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Robert Longson You closed this thread with a reference to the spec in your answer. I have prepared a detailed answer, I think the OP would be more helpful its with a detailed answer than one link and quote from the spec Please open the topic

Comment: Why not just answer the other question then?

Comment: @RobertLongson I was late with the publication of the answer literally for a minute.

Comment: I would have been interested by @Alexandr_TT answer, but the link provided when ticket has been closed helped me to fix this issue. I added `maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` in my `<mask>` element and it fixed the issue. However I was wondering if such a setting has an impact on performances (compared with the default `objectBoundingBox` value)?